# Are ceteris paribus laws of nature tautologies?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

A traditional conception of a law of nature views a hypothesis holds necessarily when it takes the logical form:

(P1) All A's are B's

(P2) O is an A

(C) Therefore O is a B.

The large number of external inputs to models proposed in the social sciences often leads to situations where P1 and P2 are true, but C is false.  Thus theorists have proposed that laws in the social sciences should be qualified with a ceteris paribus clause (all other things being equal).  An objection to this strategy suggests that this leads to a tautology of the form:

All A's are B's, *unless not*.

My question is: how can one respond to this objection?

Comment: "*The large number of external inputs to models proposed in the social sciences often leads to situations where P1 and P2 are true, but C is false.*" The obvious guess is that P1 may not actually be true at all, but rather that something like 'the vast majority of As are also Bs' or 'A-ness is strongly correlated with B-ness' is more accurate. Of course, one could attempt to classify the exceptions, to try to demonstrate that 'All As which are not Es, are Bs', but in practise I would suspect that the Es may prove various enough to spoil the pretense of a simple theory.

Comment: 'All As which are not Es, are Bs'.  Good formulation thank you.  However another aspect of a law should be explanatory so it should take the form of a conjuction such as 'If ¬Es then As are Bs'.  This also supports counterfactual conditionals of the form 'If ¬Es then As are ¬Bs'.

Comment: Could you elaborate in your question how the ceteris paribus clause leads to a tautology? This would improve your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have in mind probabilistic inferences, where P1 is not a deductive certainty, but an observational one. In such cases, the conclusion C (O is a B) is stated with some probability/confidence, but it's not certain either.

More info on this can be found at

- http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-probability/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_logic

and the references therein.